# Software that lets you move a dancer by swiping through sequences of smileys on a keyboard

Tags: android, 3d, accessibility, android-app, android-tv

I am looking for an app that does the following:

In the app, in the top part, there is a special robot called a dancer.

In the bottom part, there is a keyboard, consisting of smileys (think of Google Gboard with the keys replaced by smileys).

Each swipe (corresponding to swype in Gboard), is between one, two, or more, consecutive smileys.

Each one, maps to a dancer move, that is displayed above.

By swiping the smileys, users can discover, what the dancer can do, and can play around, to figure out, which sequences of character combinations lead to which moves.

The program, links them.

There are a relatively large (if you can program them, a large, or very large, number of combinations).

The user, enjoys, making the person in the program move.

(In fact, it is not just dance moves, but any moves made with the head, arm, leg, mouth, etc. But you don't have a button for each of these, rather, the specific convocations map to artistic dance moves in non predictable ways, but, known, one you try things out. So, it is the smileys keys that are programmed to correspond to emotions (felt or transmitted by the dancer).

But you must string them together to view the effect. Just think of leveling out the hands, adjoining fingers in special ways, bending knees slightly, rotating with one leg out, spreading a foot out at a certain angle, crossing the arms, raising one arm and placing the other down, crossing the legs, making the feet, do something, bending the neck, bending it repeatedly from one side to the other, pulling, some part of the body, ...

These are some possibilities, that can be then linked by the program in a uniform motion.

Note, there would be many more moves than keys, in a properly orchestrated program.

Think more of the smiley combinations like words in a dictionary corresponding to dance moves.

So to program this you could be a dance and movement and motion expert and augment your knowledge with watching videos of people moving, even, in slow motion, and reproducing each move sequence in the dictionary (for a dance

Thank you for your extreme interest.

I am willing to pay, for the app.

Thanks.

I have tried to add a dancing tag to this post but could not find one. It would be nice if someone could add one.